# Replace MVC page url from relative to absolute

Tags: .net, url, model-view-controller

I have web site written in asp.net mvc4. This site have page content stored in same database table. Html content is stored in table records. Now, for seo questions I need trasform all src image and href from relative url to absolute url. What is the best solutions? I think to write code for replace link url before send to View: create a static funcion i.e. using Html Agility Pack. Is possibile make a global replace i.e creating an HttpModule or a HttpFilter? 
Thanks

Comment: Ensure you use a cache if your data won't change regularly for performance. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Comment: Ok, but using HttpModule, HttpFilter or others solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I use Html Agility Pack at link http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex, create a simple parser and replace all link (filtered by regular expression). Thanks